# How can I make a row in a list view have left and right touch zones?

Tags: android

I have a ListView in my app, and I want to go to two different activities based on where the user clicks, either the left half or the right half. On iOS, I can add a tapRecognizer to each half and handle it that way, but I am not sure where to start on the Android side, and none of my google searches have come up with anything.

I'm probably using the wrong terminology, but how could I implement having a "left side" tap that goes to Activity 1 and a "right side" tap that goes to Activity 2? Both activities need to know which item was clicked, but one triggers a method of capturing images of the listed item, and the other provides additional details on the item tapped.

(I also plan on having a toggle to swap these, but I think once I know how to do it one way, I can figure out how to do it the other way).

XML for the Row:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bonusListImage"
        android:contentDescription="@string/mainImageDescription"
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/no_image_taken" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bonusListName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bonusListImage"
        android:text="@string/valueBonusName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bonusListCategory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bonusListName"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bonusListImage"
        android:text="@string/valueCategory" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bonusListCategory"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bonusListImage">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bonusListCode"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/valueBonusCode" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bonusListCity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:text="@string/valueBonusCity"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bonusListState"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:text="@string/valueBonusState"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Pic of the ListView when populated:
[image: Pic of the ListView when populated]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap it inside Framelayout and add transparent views on top of it.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bonusListImage"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/mainImageDescription"
            android:src="@drawable/no_image_taken" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bonusListName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bonusListImage"
            android:text="@string/valueBonusName" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bonusListCategory"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bonusListName"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bonusListImage"
            android:text="@string/valueCategory" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bonusListCategory"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/bonusListImage"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bonusListCode"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/valueBonusCode" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bonusListCity"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/valueBonusCity"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bonusListState"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:text="@string/valueBonusState"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/left_half"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF0" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/right_half"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#F00" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution for it. But it's not an optimal one. Let's say You have Linear layout inside your row element (card). You can first divide it into the left and right side like below.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:onClick="leftSideMethod"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <!-- left side content goes here -->

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="rightSideMethod"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!-- right side content goes here -->

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

like above mentioned code, you can add `rightSideMethod()` and `leftSideMethod()`
inside your activity like below

```
public void rightSideMethod(View view){
   //do what you want when the right side clicked
}
```

Comment: The data within the row is too large for that I think. I updated the question with a screenshot and the XML for the row.